# cookies stopped working

Tags: php, cookies, xampp

I have XAMPP 2.5.8 for Windows running on Win 7 as a development platform and just recently I lost the ability to set cookies (PHP) to expire in the future (they expire at the end of the session).

I was having a lot of problems with phpMyAdmin and upgraded it to 3.5.1. I don't know if this has anything to do with my cookie problem, but it was in the same time frame.

I've tried multiple browsers and verified that my system time is what PHP sees, but with no success.

Comment: Please provide the code?

Comment: -1. Do you explicitly specify a best before date for cookies? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the expiration time, cookie path and the domain.

You could also check if the client is overriding this behavior. e.g Firefox has an option called "Keep Cookies until I close Firefox" (Tools -Options -Privacy -Cookies) which could be having an effect.